# Application crashes when showing another window, but only when not debugging

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm an iOS-developer trying to make a small macOS-application.
I have the storyboard, and have two NSWindowController's with their viewController.

When clicking a button in the first (initial) controller, I want the other window (with its viewController).
I have tried two things:

1. Create a segue between VC1 and Window2, naming it and invoking it.
2. Instantiate with `self.storyboard?.instantiate(..)`.

Both of these work - when I run this through Xcode. But if I close Xcode and just run the resulting product, it crashes as soon as I try to open the next viewController, saying:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [32282]

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(ok:) from sender _NSPaddedButton 0x600003d0ac40

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.my.app              0x000000010d3e998e FirstViewController.openFile(at:) + 734 (SecondViewController.swift:44)
1   com.my.app              0x000000010d3e95e9 closure #1 in FirstViewController.openFile(_:) + 249
```

I'm now using this to instantiate it:

```
if let w = storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "secondWindowIdentifier") as? NSWindowController{
    if let d = w.contentViewController as? SecondViewController{
        d.doSomething(someData: myData)
        self.presentAsModalWindow(d)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It wasn't clear in the provided error, but after testing a few more times, I noticed it was sometimes showing a different error. I found one mentioning a WebView I had placed in the next view.
I had simply written `import WebKit` in the file I needed it, and hadn't added it to linked frameworks in the project's general tab. Not sure why this 100% didn't crash in the debugger, and 100% crashed on product, but oh well.